# Typescript Promise<MyClass | undefined> not returning optional variable

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, promise, undefined

I have a function basically like this

```
function foo(): Promise<MyClass | undefined> {
    if(somethingGoesWrong) {
        return Promise.resolve(undefined);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(new MyClass());
}
```

Outside the function, I call this

```
const x = await foo()
```

The problem is my IDE which is VSCode won't treat x as `MyClass | undefined`. It will just be `MyClass`.

I don't know is this an IDE problem or there are rules such as "Promise can't resolve undefined".

I know a better way to do this is probably throw some error instead of return undefined, I just want to know why is this not working or seems not working.

Comment: Do you have the `strictNullChecks` option enabled in your tsconfig file?

Comment: @CRice Thanks, it works after I add the option and restart VSCode.

Comment: If `somethingGoesWrong` then why not `reject`? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can declare that your function will return `void` instead of `undefined`.

```js
function foo(p: string): Promise<string | void> {
    if(p.length === 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(undefined);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(t);
}
```

Now, if you call your function, VSCode will comply that your function can return nothing. Vscode will underline in red .length.

```js
foo("").then((t) => {
    t.length;
});
```

You can apply the same thing for sync functions.

I chose to simplify your example by using a string instead of a class for the illustration.